# Differentiability of $f$. Given $0 < \beta < 1$ and $|f(x)|\geq |x|^ \beta $ and $f(0)=0$. Show that $f$ is not differentiable at $0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is what I have so far. I think it is the absolute value signs that are throwing me off. By the definition of derivatives,

$$
f'(0) =  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(0 +h) - f(0)} {h}= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(h)} {h}\\
$$

But now what? Since $f(0)=0$ and as $h$ tends to $0$, doesn't the the derivative read $0/0$? 
I know that I should be getting the left and the right hand limit to be different at zero. I am just failing to carry the rest of the proof through. Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since as you stated:
$$f'(0) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{|f(h)|}{h}\ge\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{|h|^\beta}{h}$$
If we approach from the right, $h>0$. Assume $f(h)>0, |\beta|<1$:
$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{|f(h)|}{h}\ge\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{|h|^\beta}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} h^{\beta-1}=\infty$$
If $f(h) <0$, we get the same divergence but to $-\infty$. The same proof follows for $h<0$.

Answer (score 0):

The result is wrong if $\beta=1$ (try $f(x)=x$). If $\beta\lt1$, this follows from
$$
\left|\frac{f(h)}h\right|\geqslant\frac1{|h|^{1-\beta}}\to\infty.
$$

Comment: I am sorry, it should have been a strict inequality. I realize why should it be. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: This is allright. While we are at it, I find funny that you accepted the only answer I do not understand. Surely you can tell me why this answer asserts that $\lim f(h)/h=\lim |f(h)|/h$.

Comment: I did not accept your answer since it was not a complete answer. As far as the point you mention, I wonder why you think that is wrong given the problem statement. Surely you can clarify that.

Comment: My comment did not ask why you did not choose my answer (which is not *incomplete*, thank you) but why you accepted the answer you accepted. Since you accepted it, of course you understood why $\lim f(h)/h=\lim |f(h)|/h$ (to me, this is not obvious since $\lim \varphi(h)=\lim|\varphi(h)|$ does not hold in general). Surely you can clarify that.

Comment: I think you are taking this too personally. Perhaps "incomplete" was not the right choice of word; I would have rather preferred a more detailed answer. You just wrote the expression and then wrote infinity (which confused me even more). In this case, I do think that the limits equal given the problem statement.

Comment: Interesting that you do not even pretend to answer the only question I am asking (and the only one which interests me): why is it clear that $\lim f(h)/h=\lim|f(h)|/h$? Just stick to the maths.

Comment: And while we are at it, why can one assume either that $f(h)\gt0$ (presumably, for every $h$ close enough to $0$) or that $f(h)\lt0$ (still in a neighborhood of $0$), although many completely different behaviours are a priori possible? Still nothing *personal*, please only the maths.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left|\frac{f(h)}{h}\right|\geq |h|^{\beta-1}.
$$
If $0\leq\beta< 1$, we have that $\beta-1$ is negative. Hence $|h|^{\beta-1}$ diverges as $h$ tends to zero and the limit $\lim_{h\to 0}f(h)/h$ does not exist.